Applications of $\frac 3 2$-generated groups
I am doing a project on $\frac 3 2$-generated groups. Besides the fact that it is really interesting to study, I was wondering if this has any useful applications, does being $\frac 3 2$-generated implies for instance some interesting properties except for the fact that every proper quotient is cyclic, or does it have some other applications?

Maybe I'm the only one, but what is a "3/2-generated group"?

I vote to close since the question lacks focus.

The following definition is often used. A group $G$ is "quasi-generated" by $\frac{3}{2}=1.5$ elements, if for all $x \in G \setminus Z(G)$, there exists a $y$ in G, such that $G =\langle x, y\rangle$. It arises in the context that every finite simple group is generated by $2$ elements,
and "quasi.generated" by $1.5$ elements. The proof goes back to Stein, see
Stein, Alexander, $1\frac{1}{2}$-generation of finite simple groups. Beiträge Algebra Geom. 39 (1998), no. 2, 349–358.
A reference, also containing links to applications, is the following MO-post:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59213/generating-finite-simple-groups-with-2-elements
Also, see this post:
A question about $\frac{3}{2}$-generated groups
